# Different size for input and anchor tags across different browsers (extra padding)

Tags: html, css, padding

Following annoying problem: [jsfiddle.net/f6juduq1](http://jsfiddle.net/f6juduq1/)

Two buttons, one **input** type="submit", the other an **a** tag, should look the same:

---

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" class="button">I'm a button</a>
<br><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="I'm a button">
```

**CSS:**

```
.button {
    background: #257abc;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;  
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    min-width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

input[type="submit"].button {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

The last line (*box-sizing*) is needed to achieve the same width. (Or min-width - the buttons should be flexible in width.)

---

Now the issues:

### Firefox 40

The inner box (inspect the first button with Firebug and click the Layout tab) is **150 x 22px**.

Second button: **150 x 24px**. Why?

---

### Chrome 45

First button (inspect with Chrome's Developer Tools): **150 x 21px**.

Second button: **150 x 21px**. Okay, but they differ from Firefox. Why?

---

### Internet Explorer 11

First button (inspect with IE's Developer Tools): **150 x 20.7px**.

Second button: **150 x 20.7px**. Okay, but "20.7" huh? Why?

---

### Safari 5.1.7

*(Can't inspect the jsfiddle's result iframe.)*

---

### Opera 31

*(Same as Chrome.)*

---

Taking a screenshot from **Firefox**'s result and comparing it in Photoshop shows the input (*second button*) is 2px higher than the a tag  (*first button*):

[image]

In **Chrome** and **Safari** it looks good:

[image]

In **IE** the **a** tag is 1px higher.

[image]

---

Now the final question is how to fix this or rather how to prevent those messy issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the major issue you're running into here is browser defaults. Your CSS styles are not resetting all of them to the same baseline. For example, Firefox gives inputs a height of `24px` by default where chrome gives an input a height of `21px` by default.

Comment: Thanks hungerstar. Like I commented below ustmaestro's answer I still have the horizontal padding problem: http://jsfiddle.net/f6juduq1/5/.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you would need to set your padding to zero or any other specific value. The issue is default properties set on various elements like `height` and `line-height`. I think @usmaestro was giving you an example. You do not have to explicitly use zero for padding top/bottom. The point he was making was make sure your line height and height are equal. I have cooked up [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/f6juduq1/6/). Setting line height equal to the height will make sure your text is vertically centered.

Comment: @hungerstar But I am understanding what @ustmaestro meant with his answer and I'm also understanding your advice. The point is, if there's a longer button text like [in your modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/f6juduq1/7/) it does not work in **Firefox**: The inner box of the a tag is **198 x 27px** whereas the inner box of the input is **204 x 27px**. I did understand that different browsers use different default settings, so you have to define `line-height` and `height`. But how exactly do I solve this Firefox issue? Thank you.

Comment: The first width fix `box-sizing: content-box;` works until the button text gets longer, from then on the inner box of the input grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The solution

Basically there are **three issues**:

1. Different box lengths
2. Different default settings across several browsers
3. Firefox CSS discrepancies

The solutions are listed below.

---

### 1. Different box lengths

An a tag is longer than an input submit:

[image]

To solve this you have to add `box-sizing: content-box;` to the input's CSS. As from now the (short) buttons look like:

[image]

### 2. Different default settings across several browsers

The buttons have different heights thanks to different browser default settings:

[image]

The input (second one) is higher.
The solution here: resetting all those defaults. Set `line-height` and `height`:

[image]

### 3. Firefox CSS discrepancies

And finally the last one, a pretty annoying behavior just in Firefox.
The buttons above are equal: same height, same width. But if the button text gets longer you might see this:

[image]

The input button is wider. This is because Firefox uses pseudo elements within the button elements. To redress this problem reset padding and border for `input::-moz-focus-inner`:

[image]

---

## The code

Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/f6juduq1/12/

### CSS

```
.button {
    background: #257abc;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    min-width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1.5;
    height: 27px; /* 18px x 1.5 = 27px */
}

input[type="submit"].button {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

input.button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

---

Thank you all for help. I hope this answer is concise & clear to help other people finding the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: I had a pseudo element pure css triangle in front of my button div and couldn't figure out why Chrome was giving the div an extra pixel in height, breaking the layout.
Adding the inline-block, line-height and height fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting observation here. The issue affects both height and width, specifically in Mozilla Firefox, due to built-in CSS style declarations.

Adding the following CSS should fix both height and width discrepancies.

```
input::-moz-focus-inner { border:0; padding:0 }
```

Illustration of the bug and fix here (notice, I've taken out your CSS styles for height:

```css
html{font-family: Arial; font-size:0.8em;}
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.button {
 background: #257abc;
 border: none;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 min-width: 150px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

input[type="submit"].button {
 box-sizing: content-box;
}

input.buttonfix::-moz-focus-inner {
  border:0;
  padding:0
}
```

```html
NOTE: Use Firefox browser to see the issue.<br>
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="" class="button">I'm a button</a>
<input type="submit" class="button buttonfix" value="I'm a button">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="I'm a button">
</div>
Notice last button has extra height forcing the container to show top/bottom of other buttons
<br>
<br>Input Button - Fixed<br>
<input type="submit" class="button buttonfix" value="I'm a much longer button">
<br>A Tag - fine<br>
<a href="" class="button">I'm a much longer button</a>
<br>Input button - bug?<br>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="I'm a much longer button">
```

Read about the issue in detail here: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/button-padding-issue/

Comment: Thanks for the solution, for your advice and for the further link. I'll post an answer which summarizes the two issues. Cheers!

Comment: I tried to summarize the issue and solution in my answer, but feel free to improve ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the same height in all browsers you need to specify the height
and for vertical align center line-height same as height value

for example try this:

```
.button {
    background: #257abc;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 20px;

    /* Adjust your height here */
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Firefox seems to set an invisible height for input tag of 1.1333 so specifically setting a height should be more consistent across browsers. These sort of issues always crop up when input boxes are involved as each browser has its own way of defining default css to style input boxes. Paddings and margins are also irregular sometimes and can throw your pixel perfect css out the window!

Comment: @trung The height problem is solved - thanks! The width problem still remains: http://jsfiddle.net/f6juduq1/8/

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with `<a>` being sized differently than `<button>` only in Safari, and it was caused by having SVG icon buttons.

The SVGs were sized at 35px, and both the anchor and button tags had explicit height of 35px set on them.

The problem was that the buttons were smaller than the anchors only in Safari.

I removed the height declarations on the buttons and it made the button take the size of the SVG inside it.